# Solve a homogeneous, linear system of algebraic equations with symbolic coefficients

Tags: equation-solving, matrix, linear-algebra

Good day to all!

I have a large system of homogeneous algebraic equations with symbolic coefficients. The following simplistic piece

```
syseqgen[k_] := Afpr[k] f[k+1] - (Afpr[k] - Af[k]) f[k] - Sum[B[k1] f[k1], {k1, 1, k}]
tabgensys[Ka_] := Table[syseqgen[k]==0, {k, 1, Ka}];
tabunk[Ka_] := Table[f[k], {k, 2, Ka}];

Solve[tabgensys[4][[1]] && tabgensys[4][[2]] && tabgensys[4][[3]], tabunk[4]]
```

provides symbolic solutions for any `Ka`. However, the output is so large that I am not able to find an explicit expression for `f[k]` for arbitrary `k`.

Is there any way to express `f[k]` in terms of sum/product of `Afpr`, `Af`, `B` and `f[1]` explicitly? Any hint or idea is highly appreciated.

Comment: What is `Ka` in your large system?

Comment: Let's say, 1000

Comment: What is the reason to have analytical expression?

Comment: System coefficients contain parameters and I need the dependence of these parameters on each `f[k]` to control the measurements of interest.